# wikipedia extraction with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wiki, wikipedia, information-retrieval

Hey so I am just beginning to learn how to use Beautiful Soup and I am having trouble pulling out the right html tags from a wikipedia page.

I am trying to pull out the individual subcategories from the sub categories section on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Furniture

however, I can't seem to figure out how to do it through all of the embedded links.  I have managed to extract the page links pretty simply with:

```
pg_links = soup.find("div" , { "id" : "mw-pages" })
```

However, when I try similar code to get the subcategories

```
sub_cats = soup.find("div" , { "class" : "CategoryTreeSection" })
```

I only get a portion of the output I want and when I try to reduce the scope;

```
sub_cats = soup.find("li" , { "class" : "CategoryTreeSection" })
```

I don't get anything at all.  Any Insight into this issue would be appreciated

---Again here is the link to the wiki page I'm trying to pull from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Furniture

Comment: The `li` items don't have that class, no. Can you elaborate (with examples) on what data you are looking to extract, exactly?

Comment: `soup.findAll("li" , { "class" : "CategoryTreeSection" })`

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to get an array with the individual subcategories.  So for example under the subcategories header on the page there is a list of categories: beds, benches, british furniture, cabinets, chairs, etc.  and I would like to pull these out so I have ['beds','benches', 'british furniture', 'cabinets',....]

Comment: Okay so now I tired:                                                                                               sub_cats = soup.find("div" , { "id" : "mw-subcategories" })                               cleaned=sub_cats.get_text()                                                                               which is getting me closer to the output I wanted but has a lot of extra newline and formatting characters and other information.  Is there a way to further specify the command.